# Javascript Array sorting with two objects (noob)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, search, replace

So i have an array with two objects like this:

```
Array(4)
0:{Activity: "Skiing", Duration: 74}
1:{Activity: "Strength training", Duration: 64}
2:{Activity: "Cycling", Duration: 64}
3:{Activity: "Running", Duration: 43}
```

The input is coming from a user which selects one out of four different activities, and then write how long the workout lasted.

And what i want to do is to sort them in a way that sums the "duration" instead of makeing a new array element.

So if the user inputs "activity" and "Duration" the array will find the right activity and increase the duration to give a total duration.
For instance if

"activity": "skiing", "Duration"= 10

Would update Duration to " 84"

```
Array(4)
0:{Activity: "Skiing", Duration: 84}
1:{Activity: "Strength training", Duration: 64}
2:{Activity: "Cycling", Duration: 64}
3:{Activity: "Running", Duration: 43}
```

I would appreciate it a lot if somebody could help me.

Comment: Is there really any sorting going on here?

Comment: As already commented, this is not a question of sorting. This is really just about incrementing the appropriate object in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr =
[
    {Activity: "Skiing", Duration: 74},
    {Activity: "Strength training", Duration: 64},
    {Activity: "Cycling", Duration: 64},
    {Activity: "Running", Duration: 43}
];

let input = {
    Activity: "Skiing",
    Duration: 12
};

arr = arr.filter(
    x => {
        if(x.Activity === input.Activity)
            x.Duration += input.Duration;

        return x;
    }
);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find` and then update the found object:

```js
const arr = [
  {Activity: "Skiing", Duration: 74},
  {Activity: "Strength training", Duration: 64},
  {Activity: "Cycling", Duration: 64},
  {Activity: "Running", Duration: 43},
];

const inputActivity = 'Cycling';
const inputDuration = 33;
const foundObj = arr.find(({ Activity }) => Activity === inputActivity);
if (foundObj) foundObj.Duration += inputDuration;
console.log(arr);
```